# How to code a program for optimization if a variable depends on optimization variables?

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a question in matlab when doing optimization. Suppose I want to to do an optimization problem on a vector of `x`

`min_x f(x,c)` such that `sum(x)=1`. For each fixed `x`, `c` is a constant, say for example

```
(x.*a+c).^(1./alpha)+(x.*b+c).^(1./alpha)=1
```

where `a,b,alpha` are known.

The algorithm is for each fixed `x` such that `sum(x)=1`, we need to find `c` from

```
(x.*a+c).^(1./alpha)+(x.*b+c).^(1./alpha)=1
```

and compute `f(x,c)`, then we update a new `x`.

Is it possible to use fmincon in matlab to solve the problem? I want to put

```
(x.*a+c).^(1./alpha)+(x.*b+c).^(1./alpha)=1
```

for the non linear constraint  in **fmincon**, but i wonder if it is valid as we do not know how to write `c` explicitly in terms of `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `solve` to write `c` explicitly in terms of `x`
- Define `f(x,c)` to be a function of `x` only
- `c` is replaced by its expression
- Start the optimization

**Please read through the comments**

```
% Given a, b, alpha
a = 2; b = 5; alpha = 1;

% Unknown x, c
syms x c

% Relation between x and c
eq = (x.*a+c).^(1./alpha)+(x.*b+c).^(1./alpha)== 1 ;

% Mention only c, x will be considered as independent variable
% The solution gives c in terms of x
c = solve(eq, c);

% Transfom syms variable into function handle variable 
c = matlabFunction(c);
% c(x) = x.*(-7.0./2.0)+1.0./2.0


% Define f as a function of x only, c is a constant having x as parameter
 fun =@(x)f(x, c(x));

% optimization starts here 

 [x, fval] = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options);


% Given function in terms of x and c
function y = f(x,c)
    y = 2.*x + c;
end
```

Comment: That's awesome!