# Are there any way to solve for an unknown variable instead of using solve?

Tags: matlab

I write code to do optimization to solve a problem taking the form `min_x f(x,c)` s.t. `sum(x)=1 and g(x,c)=1`, where `x` is a vector and `c` is a function of `x` such that `c(x)` is a constant when `x` is fixed. Indeed, `g(x,c)` takes the following form

```
n=5; N=1000000; idx = 1:1:n; df=4; theta=2; alpha=2.4;
central_Simulation_Points=mvtrnd(eyes(n),df,N);
x=sym('x_%d',[n,1]); syms c
g(x,c)=1./N.*sum((theta.*(alpha-1).*central_Simulation_Points*x).^2+c).^(1./(alpha-1)))==1;
Constraint_equ = solve(g(x,c), c);
Constraint_equ_handle = matlabFunction(Constraint_equ);
```

The use of `solve` is to express `c` in terms of `x`, while `matlabFunction` changes the symbolic function to function handle for input. I then define an objective function `obj_fun=@(x)f(x,c(x))`. The objective function for optimization is

```
(alpha-1)/alpha*sum_{i=1}^N[(theta*(alpha-1)*V(x,Xi)+c)^(1/(alpha-1))*V(x,Xi)]+c/(theta*alpha*(1-alpha))
```

`V(x,Xi)` is any function. I use `(x^{T}Xi)^2`. Xi is the i-th row of `central_Simulation_Points`.

When I count the the time, `Equ = 1./N.*sum((theta.*(alpha-1).*central_Simulation_Points*x).^2+c).^(1./(alpha-1)))==1;` takes 203 seconds to run, but it seems that `Constraint_equ = solve(Equ, c);` never makes the program stops. I wonder if any other methods could be used instead of using

```
Constraint_equ = solve(Equ, c);
Constraint_equ_handle = matlabFunction(Constraint_equ);
```

Are there any ways to find `c` in terms of `x`, or any ways to modify the code?

Comment: Kindly take your time to upvote and accept answers before re-using them. It's obvious that my previous answer has been used here related to your previous question. Read and apply stackoverflow rule if you expect answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes. The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679947/how-to-code-a-program-for-optimization-if-a-variable-depends-on-optimization-var#56679947 is fine. I appreciate it as it helps me a lot. However, I enlarge it when `x` is a vector and amend `g(x,c)` to this new case. The program never stops when I run the `solve(g(x,c), c)`. I wonder if it is possible to modify the code. I am sorry that I am new to use the platform and not clear about the regulations, but I would like to thank anyone who provides the solution in the given link and answers my current question.

Comment: In the link, `g(x,c)` has 2 terms while this time, 1000000 terms are required this time. I wonder if anyone can modify so that it works for this new case.

Comment: Alright post full objective function and the constraint, I may know how to do it. With your reputation you can do 2 things : vote up and accept. Read the link I sent you and also accept the answer below here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682126/question-about-solving-system-of-equations-using-symbolic-math

Comment: Actually you don't need to make `x` as an array `syms` variable, the purpose is expressing `c` in terms of `x`. As I said to make things just post the objective function and the constraint

Comment: Hi. I voted up and accepted. The full objective function is as follow:
`(alpha-1)/alpha*sum_{i=1}^N[(theta*(alpha-1)*V(x,Xi)+c)^(1/(alpha-1))*V(x,Xi)]+c/(theta*alpha*(1-alpha))`, where `x` is a vector being optimized, `N=1000000`, `theta` and `alpha` are some known constants, `c` should satisfy `1./N.*sum((theta.*(alpha-1).*central_Simulation_Points*x).^2+c).^(1./(alpha-1)))==1`, `central_Simulation_Points` is random points with size `N X 5`. For simplicity, treat `V(x,Xi)=x^{T}Xi`, where `Xi` is i-th row of central_Simulation_Points.

Comment: Update the original post( question) to include the function and the constraints

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195288/discussion-between-will-cheuk-and-adam).